# Add autogenerated field to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe, which does contain values

```
val cabArticleLocal = spark.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> "cabarticle"))
cabArticleLocal.show
```

```
root
 |-- is_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- cab_article: long (nullable = true)
 |-- article_id: long (nullable = true)

 +----------+-----------+----------+
 |is_enabled|cab_article|article_id|
 +----------+-----------+----------+
 +----------+-----------+----------+
```

that will be inserted into a PostgreSQL database with this structure

```
id 
is_enabled
cab_article
article_id
```

How can I generate a field id into the dataframe to be something with autogenerated id inserted to existing dataframe .
Thanks

```
+----------+-----------+----------+---+
|is_enabled|cab_article|article_id| id|
+----------+-----------+----------+---+
+----------+-----------+----------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `monotonically_increasing_id` function as the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
cabArticleLocal.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

or you can use `row_number` function over `Window` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
cabArticleLocal.withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("article_id")))
```

Or you can use a query language as

```
cabArticleLocal.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")
sqlContext.sql("select row_number() over (order by article_id) as id,is_enabled,cab_article,article_id from tempTable")
```